# Accessing an element from a response in bash

Tags: bash

I'm sending a curl request in bash and need to deal with a possible bad response such as the following:

```
{"errors":["You’ve performed this action too many times. Please wait 20 seconds before trying again."],"error_type":"rate_limit","extras":{"wait_seconds":20}}
```

Specifically, I need to access the number of seconds which is said in the "errors" or in the "wait_seconds" so I can wait that period of time and then send the request again. I've tried using different combinations of grep, cut and sed to no avail. Any feedback would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: have you tried using `jq`?

Comment: @Jon command will do it or you can use awk `echo $res | awk '{split($0,a,":"); print a[5];}' | cut -d '}' -f 1`

Comment: OR `secs=$(sed 's/^.*Please wait //;s/seconds.*$//')` .Good luck.

Comment: OR `secs=$(sed 's/^.*wait_seconds"://;s/}}//')`

Answer (score 0):

With `grep`:

```
echo ${response} | grep -Po '"wait_seconds":\K\d+'
```

If you have access to `jq`:

```
echo ${response} | jq .extras.wait_seconds
```